# Data structure for apriori algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-structures, apriori, market-basket-analysis

How can I restructure my data in Python to use the Apriori algorithm? I have a dataset with two columns: "Article" and "ID". The "Article" column contains either a single number or a list of numbers. I want to convert the data into a matrix format where each article corresponds to a column, each transaction corresponds to a row, and the values are filled with "true" or "false" depending on whether the article exists in the corresponding transaction. For example, given the following data:

```
| ID  | Articles  |  
| ID1 | [1, 2, 3] | 
| ID2 | [1, 2]    | 
| ID3 | 4         |
```

I want to convert it to the following format:

```
|     | 1   | 2   |   3 | 4     |  
| ID1 | true| true| true| false | 
| ID2 | true| true|false| false |
| ID3 |false|false|false| true  |
```

This matrix format will allow me to apply the Apriori algorithm. how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you include the code you have, and include some sample input (in the code), and explain what the desired output is for that example input?

Comment: for example this is my data : 
| ID  | Articles           |
|-----|--------------------|
| ID1 | [1, 2, 3]       |
| ID2 | [1, 2]       |
| ID3 | 4       |
I wanna convert it to this format : 
|     | 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| ID1 | true| true| true| false|
| ID2 | true| true| false| false|
| ID3 | false| false| false| true|
In order to apply apriori algorithm. Thank you so much !

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information. But it will not be enough: we expect you to include your code that you are trying with and a question that is focused on a problem with that code.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet, but I need assistance in converting my data into a matrix format suitable for the Apriori algorithm in Python.
Sorry if my description wasn't clear I have made edits and I hope it is now clear. Thank you !